# Issue with cloning linux kernel git repo

Tags: linux, git

For the past few days, I've been trying to download and build the Linux kernel to follow a book on kernel development.

Unfortunately, during the simple phase of cloning my terminal disappears, and thus the clone is incomplete.

These are my two commands:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
git clone git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
```

It fails after several minutes in the cloning phase something happens and the terminal stops and disappears.

I've wondered if this could be due to a few initial reasons:

- I'm using a virtual machine Ubuntu: 90Gb/4Gb RAM/ 2CPU (VirtualBox).
- Insufficient storage space within the virtual machine.
- Connectivity problems.
- The virtual machine is running sluggishly.

However, even after switching virtual machines, increasing storage, and checking other factors, the problem persists.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Comment: what is the exact command you are running? what do you mean by your command prompt disappears?   usually the command you'd run would be `git clone <URL>` where URL would be the value you provided.  You shuold run that from a terminal I dont know what an Ubuntu command prompt is.

Comment: Just for the record, please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Hello @UpAndAdam, i mean my terminal sorry ! literally, the terminal literally disappears! When I restart it it is empty, so I have to restart the command! I specify that my git clone of personal project or other works very well

Comment: what does works very well mean? you still havent provided the exact command you used to perform the git clone.... so voting to close.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Wait for the main topic I didn't say something worked and for the command:

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git and 
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git ! I will add some precision in my post

Comment: Try watching the system logs in another terminal, and/or examine the output of `top`. Sounds like you are running out of memory. You'd see an OOM message in the system log when this happens.

Comment: Remove the second command it is just flat out wrong. Only the first one is correct.

Comment: when you reopen the terminal what is left where the clone had started? is the linux.git directory there?  my money suspects you have far too little ram